# Highcharts pie chart - offset a single slice on legend click

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I've been searching through the [API docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) and lots of examples, but can't seem to find what I want.

I have a pie chart with a legend. When you click a slice, it becomes offset (this is great). I would like this behaviour when you click on a legend item.

Is it possible to achieve an offset slice via legend click?

So if you click on an item in the legend, the relevant slice becomes offset.

It seems that the method to use is [`legendItemClick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick), eg:

```
options: {
     chart: {
         type: 'pie'
     },
     plotOptions: {

      //etc

      series: {
        point: {
          events: {

            legendItemClick: function () {

              //return false; // this cancels the default action.

              console.log(this);

              //this.findtheSlice.makeItOffset();  //want to do something like this

            }

          }
        }
      }

    //etc

    }
  }
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95n2mm02/2/)

It seems that there isn't a method available to achieve this so may need to go deep into the api.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Btw, i'm using an angular directive for highcharts (highcharts-ng). There are some subtle differences.

Comment: Based on [this code](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/highcharts.src.js#L18184) I can only answer that you could achieve behavior you desire only by modifying library code

Comment: @Andrey Thanks, would like to avoid modifying the library if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the legendItemClick you should call `this.slice()` and then return false.

```
           point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        this.slice();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/95n2mm02/4/

Comment: Excellent, thank you Sebastian - beautifully simple!